# Parse rows by date filter (Google Tables)

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

How could I parse rows from my table by dates (logic for example: today is 3 more days until the delivery date) and place it into another sheet?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TTbIX3qNKXyQAQiJ2EuRNDKWy1YEhLBPzsVw8mxMhKs

I need to run this script  automatically (or manually) every day to update a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=filter(A2:C; C2:C-today() <=3)
```

Comment: How can i add condition >0 to this formula?

Comment: =filter(A2:C; C2:C-today() <=3; C2:C-today() >0)